# Asymptotic behaviour of the solution to some delayed stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the delayed stochastic differential equation as below:

$$dX_t^\theta=X_{(t-\theta)^+}^\theta(1-X_{(t-\theta)^+}^\theta)(dt+dW_t),\quad \forall t>0$$

$$dY_t^\theta=Y_{(t-\theta)^+}^\theta(1-Y_{(t-\theta)^+}^\theta)dt +Y_{t}^\theta(1-Y_{t}^\theta)dW_t ,\quad \forall t>0,$$

where $x^+:=\max(x,0)$, $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\theta\ge 0$ is a fixed constant. For any $z\in [0,1]$, the above equations are well posed with $X_0^\theta:=z$ and $Y_0^\theta:=z$. My question is whether we always have

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}X_t^\theta\in \{0,1\},\quad  \lim_{t\to\infty}Y_t^\theta\in \{0,1\}?$$

It follows from [Almost sure stability of a scalar, nonautonomous, nonlinear SDE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290870/almost-sure-stability-of-a-scalar-nonautonomous-nonlinear-sde?rq=1) that the claim holds for $\theta=0$. I wish to know how the delay $\theta$ may change fundamentally the asymptotic behaviour.