# Asymptotic behaviour of the solution to some delayed ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Following the previous post [Asymptotic behaviour of the solution to some delayed stochastic differential equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450065/asymptotic-behaviour-of-the-solution-to-some-delayed-stochastic-differential-equ) I consider a deterministic version (as no answer is received) :

$$\frac{d x^\theta}{d t} =F\big(x^\theta((t-\theta)^+)\big),\quad \forall t>0$$

$$\frac{d x}{d t}=F\big(x(t)\big),\quad \forall t>0,$$

where $\theta\ge 0$, $x^\theta, x$ are functions taking values in $\mathbb R^d$ and $F:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R^d$ is bounded and Lipschitz. For any $z\in \mathbb R^d$, the above ODEs are well posed with $x^\theta(0):=z$ and $x(0):=z$. Assume further the solutions $x^\theta, x$ are bounded.

If $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)$ exists, under which condition one has  $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}x^\theta(t)$? Can we prove the desired equality when $\theta>0$ is small enough or find an counterexample?